# Go to current state after pushing an older commit into github

Tags: git, github

Sorry if the title is not clear. I wasn't sure what to write. 
What I want to ask is I'm working on a project and I made a commit a few days back but didn't push it. Since then I made numerous changes to the code and even added a lot of files too. Yesterday, I decided to push the code into github. While doing that I first pushed the previously made commit into the github. But now my repo has been reset to that previous commit. All the changes that I've made and new files that I've created since that commit are gone.
I'd like to know if all those changes and files are permanently gone? If not, how to get it back?

Comment: Does `git checkout <branch>` bring your changes back? That's the normal way to reset your copy to the head of a given branch. Also, `git push` implicitly pushes _all_ commits along the current branch that aren't in the remote repo so it's not usually necessary to push individual older commits.

Comment: No, git checkout <branch> doesn't bring my changes back. That is the problem, I didn't make a new commit. I just pushed the older one.

Comment: @janos ... sorry I am new to github I don't know the terms well. I just pushed a commit I made a few days back and now my repo is back to the state when I made that commit.

Comment: Did you commit your other changes too? What is the output of `git status`. Do you use branches? What is the output of `git branch -vv`?

Comment: When you pushde to github, I guess it asked you to update your local repository. Did you do a `git pull` ?

Comment: If you are using a GUI, check if it has automatically stashed all your changes. In which case, you only need to pop that stash

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `git reflog`. This should give you a list similar to below

[image: reflog]

Besically, this keeps a track on the actions you've carried out which triggered change in `HEAD` pointer

If you want to reset back to some previous state, say before you've done your `pull`... or before you've done a bad `git reset --hard ...`

You can find in this list the action which triggered the change in your working directory and then reset it to `HEAD` prior to this action using:

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{4}
```

> HEAD@{4}

**THE ABOVE IS ONLY AN EXAMPLE YOU MUST REPLACE IT WITH WHATEVER HEAD YOU WANT TO GO BACK TO**